# Redirect all except local IPs to different directory, htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I would like any 192.168.0.* address to be able to access my webserver as usual, which will give it the www directory. This already works, but unfortunately it will also allow outside IP's to access the same directory.
I want to redirect anyone not on a local IP address to be directed to the AGCS directory and be allowed to browser through it, as it is a normal website.

Example:
192.168.0.1 tries to access 192.168.0.2, sees the directory it now shows

Bill at 1.3.3.7 tries to access, and is redirected to the working website in the AGCS directory and does not know he has been redirected

Thanks to assistance, I am currently seeing partial success. My .htaccess file in the www directory looks as such:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192.168.0
RewriteRule ^ /AGCS/ [L,R]

And my .htaccess file in the AGCS directory looks as such:
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Unfortunately I am currently researching how to write a conditional where if the user is accessing something in the AGCS directory or lower, they do not get redirected but do not know how as of yet. The current solution states that I have a redirect loop.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried to deny everyone except local addresses, and if they were denied redirect to the correct directory but it wound up breaking, i'm not sure why.

Comment: I just got it to work, providing answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your www directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.0
RewriteRule ^ /AGCS/ [L,R]
```

(or wherever the AGCS directory is)

in the htaccess file in your AGCS directory

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
```

Comment: This somewhat worked. Currently it redirects as intended, but unfortunately if accessed from outside of the local ip address range, it says that there is a redirect loop. I think I need a conditional where if the person is accessing something within the AGCS directory or deeper, they do not get redirected again, but I unfortunately do not know how to write this and am researching it on google at the moment.

Comment: As long as the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/AGCS/* line is added after RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.0 line in order to prevent a redirect loop, this successfully solves my problem as of the moment, unless further issues arise from this. Thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminPlonk Ah ok, I think another thing you could have done is add `RewriteEngine On` to the htaccess file in your AGCS directory, with no rules.

Comment: Add an additional condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/AGCS/` before `RewriteRule ^ /AGCS/ [L,R]` to prevent problems loading images or other resources from the redirected folder.